Opening flutter progress widget before expensive / long task
So I'm struggling with the following seemingly easy concept - I want to open a progress indicator then start a long task and then close it once the task is completed.
Here's my flow:

press button, in the onTap function show the progress bar (using showDialog)
start the long task (PDF generation and mailing)
once the task is completed hide the spinner from step one

It's not working as it should, the spinner only appears once the PDF generation and mailing is almost done, it stays up for few seconds then disappears. It's almost as if the UI thread is blocked.
The PDF generation task returns future, and the onTap is async. I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong here. How can i show the spinner before starting the long task?

check https://dart.dev/language/concurrency, remember that flutter runs in single thread so most likely if your long task takes couple of seconds (i mean a tight loop used for PDF generation - "as if the UI thread is blocked.") you need https://dart.dev/language/concurrency#isolates

Isolate.run() helped! Thank you sir!

Just putting it here for anybody having similar problem.
As psking suggested in the comment Flutter concurrency is the solution.
I used Isolate.run() to isolate the PDF generation and then everything works like a charm.
